# Unable to run Scrapy: “ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3Download Handler': DLL load failes

Tags: python, dll, scrapy, importerror

Trying to learn how to use scrapy, I got this error when launching 'scrapy crawl dmoz':

```
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.18.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.
py", line 40, in load_object
    raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3Download
Handler': DLL load failed: Le module spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
```

I am running on a Win8 64bit and python 2.7 32bits is installed. All versions of binaries packages installed are for 2.7 and 32bits. I couldn't find any answers relative to this problem (except from incompatibility of bianries packages and python).

any idea of how to fix it ?
Thanks !

Comment: (end of the code : the specified module couldnt be found")